What is the fastest way to query for items with an existing foreign key and many-to-many entry in Django?
I have a simple model with a foreign key and a many-to-many relationship:
class Car(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField()
    is_red = models.BooleanField()

class Owner(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, to_field="uuid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Driver(models.Model):
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(ProtectedArea, related_name="cars")

Now a lot of my application logic relies on cars on which at least one of the three conditions: it is red, it has at least one owner, it has at least one driver is true. It might be an important information, that in reality the Car-model contains some rather big polygonal data, maybe that is relevant for performance here?
I have a custom manager for this but now matter how I built the query it seems extremely slow. Times are taken from my local dev machine with ~50k cars, 20k Owners, 1.2k Drivers. The view is a default FilterView from django-filter without any filters being actually active.
My manager currently looks like this:
class ActiveCarManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        cars_with_owners = Owner.objects.values("car__uuid").distinct()
        cars_with_drivers = Drivers.objects.values("cars__uuid").distinct()

        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(
                Q(uuid__in=cars_with_owners)
                | Q(uuid__in=cars_with_drivers)
                | Q(is_red=True)
            )
        )

The view generates 2 queries from this, one count query and one query to fetch the actual items. The query that is so slow is the count query. On our staging instance this reguarly takes several seconds to complete. Here are the generated SQL and the query plan:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "app_car"
 WHERE ("app_car"."uuid" IN (SELECT DISTINCT U0."car" FROM "app_owner" U0) OR "app_car"."uuid" IN (SELECT DISTINCT U2."uuid" FROM "app_driver" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_driver_cars" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."driver_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_car" U2 ON (U1."car_id" = U2."id")) OR "app_car"."is_red" = TRUE)

Aggregate  (cost=32426.52..32426.53 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=951.281..951.289 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on app_car  (cost=13300.79..32335.30 rows=36485 width=0) (actual time=20.850..950.695 rows=3687 loops=1)
        Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2) OR (is_red IS TRUE))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 44147
        SubPlan 1
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=556.68..580.34 rows=2366 width=16) (actual time=6.713..6.940 rows=2366 loops=1)
                Group Key: u0.park
                Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 241kB
                ->  Seq Scan on app_owner u0  (cost=0.00..508.57 rows=19245 width=16) (actual time=0.007..3.970 rows=19245 loops=1)
                      Filter: approved
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 12
        SubPlan 2
          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12669.76..12705.58 rows=3582 width=16) (actual time=12.404..12.718 rows=3009 loops=1)
                Group Key: u2.uuid
                Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 369kB
                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.86..12660.81 rows=3582 width=16) (actual time=0.090..10.961 rows=3585 loops=1)
                      ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.56..238.42 rows=3582 width=8) (actual time=0.065..1.403 rows=3585 loops=1)
                            Merge Cond: (u0_1.id = u1.driver_id)
                            ->  Index Only Scan using driver_id_pkey on driver_id u0_1  (cost=0.28..70.02 rows=2249 width=8) (actual time=0.036..0.388 rows=2249 loops=1)
                                  Heap Fetches: 0
                            ->  Index Only Scan using driver_id_park_id_car_cb09e8dc_uniq on driver_id_carss u1  (cost=0.28..118.01 rows=3582 width=16) (actual time=0.026..0.435 rows=3582 loops=1)
                                  Heap Fetches: 0
                      ->  Memoize  (cost=0.30..4.11 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=3585)
                            Cache Key: u1.car_id
                            Cache Mode: logical
                            Hits: 576  Misses: 3009  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 377kB
                            ->  Index Scan using app_car_pkey on app_car u2  (cost=0.29..4.10 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=3009)
                                  Index Cond: (id = u1.car_id)
Planning Time: 5.902 ms
Execution Time: 952.436 ms

Interestingly the Query Plan states that it took 952ms, however Django Debug Toolbar reports 2162ms ...
edit: changing this as proposed in the answer changes the SQL and query plan accordingly (but to the worse):
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "app_car"
 WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "app_car" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_owner" U1 ON (U0."uuid" = U1."car") WHERE (U1."id" IS NULL AND U0."uuid" = ("app_car"."uuid")) LIMIT 1)) OR NOT (EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "app_car" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_driver_cars" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."car_id") WHERE (U1."driver_id" IS NULL AND U0."id" = ("app_car"."id")) LIMIT 1)) OR "app_car"."is_red" IS TRUE)

 Aggregate  (cost=2394123.29..2394123.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1409.060..1409.070 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on app_car  (cost=0.00..2394032.07 rows=36485 width=0) (actual time=517.456..1408.560 rows=3687 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) OR (NOT (hashed SubPlan 4)) OR (is_red IS TRUE))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 44147
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2059.73..2618.84 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=52.292..59.881 rows=45468 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (u1.car = u0.uuid)
                Filter: (u1.id IS NULL)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 19257
                ->  Seq Scan on app_owner u1  (cost=0.00..508.57 rows=19257 width=24) (actual time=0.052..2.406 rows=19257 loops=1)
                ->  Hash  (cost=1461.80..1461.80 rows=47834 width=16) (actual time=47.111..47.115 rows=47834 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2755kB
                      ->  Index Only Scan using rules_prote_uuid_cec594_idx on app_car u0  (cost=0.29..1461.80 rows=47834 width=16) (actual time=0.035..13.607 rows=47834 loops=1)
                            Heap Fetches: 0
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.68..1605.98 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=36.365..50.746 rows=44826 loops=1)
                Merge Cond: (u0_1.id = u1_1.car_id)
                Filter: (u1_1.driver_id IS NULL)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 3582
                ->  Index Only Scan using app_car_pkey on app_car u0_1  (cost=0.29..1249.80 rows=47834 width=8) (actual time=0.051..7.282 rows=47834 loops=1)
                      Heap Fetches: 0
                ->  Index Scan using app_driver_cars_car_id_5861f4f4 on app_driver_cars u1_1  (cost=0.28..191.82 rows=3582 width=16) (actual time=0.040..1.300 rows=3582 loops=1)
Planning Time: 8.782 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 39
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.579 ms, Inlining 83.217 ms, Optimization 223.561 ms, Emission 125.051 ms, Total 434.408 ms
Execution Time: 1445.534 ms

Do you have any idea how I can speed this up? Or should I use a dedicated "is_active" column and update it using signals?

You can optimize this to:
class ActiveCarManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):

        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(~Q(owner=None) | ~Q(cars=None) | Q(is_red=True))
            .distinct()
        )
The related_name=… parameter [Django-doc] however is the name of the relation in reverse, so from the Car model to the Driver model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the cars relation to drivers.
If we rename the related_name=…, it is:
class ActiveCarManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):

        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(~Q(owner=None) | ~Q(drivers=None) | Q(is_red=True))
            .distinct()
        )

Or should I use a dedicated "is_active" column and update it using signals?

I would strongly advise against that. Then you move the burden to the signals working properly. Signals however tend to be "very painful". Indeed, you will need to know if an Owner is created, updated, removed, if a Driver changes what Cars it drives, is removed, etc. While that may look simple, the number of cases can grow very fast, and furthermore, signals don't run when you do bulk updates, so it is likely that eventually the signal will not be triggered. See this article I wrote about signals [django-antipatterns].

Thanks willem. I had tried this before, however this actually decreases the performance. Might this be an index issue because I am not using the pk but the uuid maybe?

You can use db_index=True on the UUIDField yes.

It already has that. I thought maybe the m2m indexing isn't working properly with that. Anyways, any other idea why your suggestion is slower?

@tommueller: what is the queryplan?

I added the generated query and query plan after your proposed changes to the question
